# Adding cordova to existing angular-lungo template

Tags: javascript, web-applications, android

I am trying to figure out how I would go about adding cordova to my project which has angular.js and lungo.js included in it. Here's the error I get :

```
Error: Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project.
```

How would I make it a Cordova project?

I also tried the other way around. That was : By creating a cordova project first, then adding angular.js and lungo.js in it. I'm using grunt to init the scaffold template.

Here's the error:

```
Philippes-MacBook-Pro:hello Phil$ grunt-init lungo-angular-bridge
Running "init:lungo-angular-bridge" (init) task
This task will create one or more files in the current directory, based on the
environment and the answers to a few questions. Note that answering "?" to any
question will show question-specific help and answering "none" to most questions
will leave its value blank.

Warning: Existing files may be overwritten! Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Now, I'm not sure how I could make cordova, angular.js, lungo.js all be included correctly.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you,
Phil.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would check is if the `.cordova` file is being created.
If not, try running this command from the repository: `cordova create`